# my sortable playlist li's are stacking on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, socket.io, jquery-ui-sortable

So I'm trying to make a playlist that i will be able to move the place of the songs and after im trying to move the li it just get stacked on top of each other.

```
$( function() {
            $( "#playlist" ).sortable({
              change: function(event, ui) {

                socket.send({'msg_type':"update_playlist", 'info' : event.target.innerHTML , room : page, user:id21});
              },
              refreshPositions: true,
              axis: 'y',
            });
            $( "#playlist" ).disableSelection();

          } );
```

in the socket I'm sending the message type the sortable  ul and all the li's inside and I'm sending other info of the account and room. 
i tried to make an timeout and it didn't help making the li's stack .